# Can I create a CRAM file with a relative reference path?

Tags: sam, samtools, cram

I’m trying to create a CRAM file that stores its path to the FASTA reference as a relative path, rather than an absolute path, so that I can move the files around. Unfortunately I can’t get this to work; I was expecting the following to work:

```bash
⟩⟩⟩ samtools view -C -T ../reference/ref.fa -o output.cram input.bam
```

However, the resulting file contains an absolute path in its header:

```bash
⟩⟩⟩ samtools view -H output.cram
…
@SQ     SN:1    LN:249250621    M5:hash     UR:/absolute/path/to/data/mapped/../reference/ref.fa
…
```

As a result, I am unable to open the file via a different path mount that results in different absolute paths, and I can’t move the file (+ its reference) around, or to different machines.

I know that I could set the `REF_PATH` environment variable or specify `-T` when reading the file but I would like to avoid this (the result file needs to be readable by IGV, launched by users who don’t know how to set environment variables).

Is there a way of creating a CRAM file that stores a *relative path* to its reference?

Comment: Can you reheader the file? I'm curious if stripping the absolute path works that way.

Comment: BTW, ideally the hash should suffice to looking up the reference (assuming IGV supports this).

Comment: I have a feeling this should be raised on hts-specs then. What you’re trying to do should really be supported.

Comment: This would seem like a rather glaring oversight which won't help with the adoption of CRAM at all, as it effectively makes CRAM unportable which somewhat limits it's utility for an archive format.

Comment: The primary way of finding the right reference sequences for a CRAM file is via the `M5` hash, which is far more useful in an archival context than a file path on someone else's potentially long-gone filesystem.

If there's an issue to be raised, it's against htslib which unconditionally makes the file path absolute when adding `UR` from a `-T` argument. You would indeed be able to set it arbitrarily when reheadering.

Answer (score 1):

In your CRAM file, make all of the reference sequences present in the `./` directory. Then make a bash script to make relative links to your reference for whatever mount you are using at the time - ie `ln -s TARGET LINK_NAME`.

Now your CRAM is portable and you just have to tailor the local working dir to it.